# If there are duplicates (For column A, B, and C) delete both occurrences

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code (shown below) which deletes values if they are duplicates. It is currently only checking column A, however, I need it to check if column A, B, and C are the same and if they are, then I need to delete them.

Any suggestions are extremely appreciated

```
Sub stacks()
Sheets("Changed Dates").Select

Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Dim rngA As Variant
rngA = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, 1))
Dim rngB As Variant
rngB = Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(lastRow, 2))
Dim rngC As Variant
rngC = Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(lastRow, 3))
Dim i As Long, rngDel As Range
Set rngDel = Nothing
For i = LBound(rngA) To UBound(rngA)
    If rngA(i, 1) = rngB(i, 1) = rngC(i, 1) Then
        rngDel = Union(rngDel, Rows(i))
    End If
Next i
If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.Delete

End Sub
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ro2uS.png)

Comment: Please include your code as text in your question

Comment: what have you tried thusfar?  my first thought is to capture all three ranges as arrays, looping if A is found in B or C and if B is found in C (think 'select'); if any of those match, add the rows to an array and delete those row numbers via union.  This also depends if you need matches in all 3, as opposed to 2/3 matches.

Comment: If one field (column a, b, or c) is different, I do not want either row to be deleted. If all three fields are the same, I would like both lines to be deleted

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these have the same number of rows per columns, you can use something like the following (untested):

```
'*Edited code, post-testing*
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim rngA As Variant
    rngA = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, 1))
    Dim rngB As Variant
    rngB = Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(lastRow, 2))
    Dim rngC As Variant
    rngC = Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(lastRow, 3))
    Dim i As Long, rngDel As Range
    Set rngDel = Nothing
    For i = LBound(rngA) To UBound(rngA)
        Select Case True
            Case rngA(i, 1) = rngB(i, 1) And rngB(i, 1) = rngC(i, 1)
                If rngDel Is Nothing Then
                    Set rngDel = Rows(i)
                Else
                    Set rngDel = Union(rngDel, Rows(i))
                End If
        End Select
    Next i
    If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.Delete
```

We define our last row, then our ranges for columns A, B, and B.  From there, you assess if the values in the same row are equal; if they are all three equal, then add that row to a range to be deleted (non-contiguous ranges joined via `union`).  Finally, we delete the delete range.

Comment: It is throwing a compile error: Invalid use of object... when I select Okay, it highlights the sub line and the last 'Nothing' is highlighted in blue?

Comment: @Inmohelpdesk the fun of untested, off the cuff code... going to guess it should be `if not rngDel is nothing then rngDel.delete`

Comment: I really appreciate the help and effort. Its now throwing a runtime error on the line "If rngA(i) = RngB(i) = rangC(i) then"

Comment: @Inmohelpdesk looks like your naming could be an issue... or it needs to be `rngA(i,1) = rngB(i,1) = rngC(i,1)`; the arrays stored by copying ranges from the sheet are multi-dimensional

Comment: Now getting an error on rngDel line (invalid procedure)

Comment: @Inmohelpdesk please edit your post to include your new code.

Comment: Done with that.

Comment: @Inmohelpdesk check my answer, now; i did some testing and put in a check for the union, as well as added `and` modifier to `rngA = rngB = rngC`, since those are two separate checks

Comment: code is working, however, it is not deleting anything

Comment: @Inmohelpdesk at that point, i believe it's a data concern.  I just tested it again with a few a small data set (fibonacci in col A, 1-10 in col B & C; it was deleting the rows 1 and 5).